# Helm-projectile comes with docker-tramp, and haven't figured a way to solve it

Tags: helm, tramp, helm-projectile, helm-sources, helm-for-files

I use Doom Emacs. When starting with an empty configuration and adding the following line:

```
(use-package! helm-projectile
    :custom
    (helm-projectile-on))
```

Save it and restart Emacs, then I get this warning:
[image]

It's caused by that only one line, the rest of my configuration is empty. This puzzles me because I'm using helm-projectile only in my configuration. When I remove the use-package declaration of helm-projectile, this warning doesn't come up anymore.

When I looked into the helm-projectile repository, there were no issues tracked about this. When looked for an projectile alternative that integrates well with my Helm setup and Ag projectile, there was no suitable alternative.

So I have to find a way to redirect helm-projectile to use docker-tramp or disable docker-tramp for projectile only. WHen looking in the source code of helm-projectile, I couldn't find any references to docker-tramp, so I'm bit more puzzled.

I tried to look into variables of helm-projectile which would allow me to disable docker-tramp, but alas, there are no references of this.

What would be the best way to approach this, to get rid of the warning?

Answer (score 1):

Check variable `load-history`. This should tell you where `docker-tramp` is loaded from.

Answer (score -1):

Just file a bug report or ignore the warning.

Comment: The helm-projectile repository is abandoned by the author, all the commits come from previous year before the latest and there are issues which are never answered by the author for in 3 years. So it would be bit useless to fill an issue there, it seems. I cannot ignore the warning to keep my setup sane. This warning keeps bothering me with popping up windows every time when I start Emacs.

Comment: If the package is abandoned (or the author considers it stable and finished, which often looks the same), then I suppose you’ll have to fix the bug yourself. Or perhaps your bug report will be the one which prods the author back into action (I’ve been in that situation myself). Or, if nothing else, your bug report will let other users know about the problem, and maybe one of them will fix it. Always report the bug!

Comment: You may want to raise a bug with the doom maintainers also: your config may be almost empty but (according to your screenshot) doom has loaded 264 packages so there is a lot of possibility for weird interactions.